# Django and uuid generated by database

Tags: django, postgresql, uuid

I'm creating a rest api using Django and DRF.
I don't want to expose IDs directly to client so I'm trying to setup my models like this example:

```
class AbstractGuidModel(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(blank=True, default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class MyModel(AbstractGuidModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=NAME_LENGTH)
```

Since the AbstractGuidModel has **default=uuid.uuid4**, uuid are generated by python code and migrations look like:

```
CREATE TABLE "MyModel" ( ... "uuid" uuid NOT NULL UNIQUE, ... );
```

I've read Postgres has an extension for generating automatically uuids.

Once extension is installed, how can I tell django to let database use his own extension and not letting him create them with the Python uuid module?

Answer (score -1):

When you use UUIDField as a primary key in Django, it doesn't generate a UUID one for you, you generate it yourself before you save the object. Your code does that and it works fine.

The UUIDField will be stored against the Postgres UUID Field.

Comment: I don't want to use uuid as primary key, my models still use default numeric autoincrement ids. I'm using uuid to expose the record through apis without letting api consumers peculiar informations about records (creation sequence, etc etc). I'd just want the Postgres to generate uuids by himself instead of using Python uuid module

Comment: Yes and your code will do that (except the Postgres generating the uuid part). Your 'MyModel' object will have an id, name, and uuid. Uuid will be set by the default function before it is saved to the db. The only value that Postgres would populate in this case is the id.